# I can't create new account via rpc with personal_newAccount

Tags: json-rpc

I want to create new account via rpc

curl -X POST http://localhost:8545 -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_newAccount","params":["1234567890"],"id":11}'

but this command return this error instead

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":11,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"local keystore not used"}}

Comment: The `personal_newAccount` is deprecated you have to use clef to manage accounts https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/account-management.

Comment: Past 2 years am using personal_newAccount method how to fix this issue in this method kindly advice me